# hide video download link in wordpress - let no one to see video download link

Tags: wordpress, html5-video

i want everyone can see my video in my website ( cms : wordpress v 3.7.1 )
but let no one to download my video !
( let no one to see video download link 
like : 
http://dl.antilicense.com/how-to-active-trustport.webm 
in page:
http://antilicense.com/?p=4119
)
what I must to do ?
my video player plugin is sz-video

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[If you can read it, you can copy it](https://superuser.com/a/391885/68374).

A determined enough user will be able to dig out the URL for the video and download it. Or at least screen record it. Don't waste your time trying to keep this from happening. See this [topic being discussed here](https://superuser.com/a/601200/68374).

That being said, and assuming you don't care about screen copies (which degrade the quality of the video) one of the hardest platforms to download video from (AFAIK) is [Brightcove](http://www.brightcove.com/). Another option is [Adobe Flash real-time encryption](http://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-media-server/kb/protect-video-content-flash-media.html). These two are not consumer grade solutions - you need to sign up and be ready to spend some money & time to put it in place.